# Pawn compiler in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: pawn

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskLabel": "tarefa-pawncc",
      "appliesTo": "pawno/pawncc.exe",
      "type": "launch",
      "contextType": "build",
      "args": ["${relativeFile}"],
      "command": "${workspaceRoot}\\pawno\\pawncc.exe"
    }
  ]
}
```

The compilation does not work, I get this message:

> ------ Build iniciado: projeto: pawncc, Configuração:  ------
> D:\samp server lfn\pawno\pawno\pawncc.exe :
> error 075: input line too long (after substitutions)

Using an external tool, all work perfectly, but when I try to use the task I can't compile

This screenshot shows the problem:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sGjy.jpg)